# NPE filling list of (sub) objects in custom object

Tags: java, android, list, nullpointerexception

I am trying to put some data in a list of custom objects. One of the items in my main custom objects is a list of photos, containing two strings. But everytime i try to add a photo-item i get an nullpointerexception...

my code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String language =  Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("MyJson.json");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Log.i("tijdlog","start parsing" );
    try {

        List<JJsonResponse> jsonResponse = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<List<JJsonResponse>>() { });
        Log.i("tijdlog","ended json parsing" );
        final List<JJsonResponse> myGlobalVariable = jsonResponse;

        //Simple Venues maken, rest weggooien!
        List<SimpleVenue> sv = new ArrayList<SimpleVenue>();
        JJsonResponse e;
        int k =0; //indicator 1e SimpleVenue
        JVenueThemes jtheme;
        SimpleVenue tempSv;
        SimplePhotos tempPhoto;
        int selectedCounter;

        for(int i=0;i < jsonResponse.size() ;i++) {
            e = jsonResponse.get(i);
            if(e.venue.hidden == false) { //staat aan
                for(int j=0; j<e.venue.themes.size();j++) { //loop door alle themes
                    if (e.venue.themes.get(j).mobile == true) {  //als theme is true
                        jtheme = e.venue.themes.get(j);
                        sv.add(new SimpleVenue());
                        tempSv=sv.get(k);
                        tempSv.setId(k);
                        tempSv.setName(e.venue.name);
                        tempSv.setAdress(e.venue.address);
                        tempSv.setCity(e.venue.city);
                        tempSv.setPhone(e.venue.phone);
                        tempSv.setWebsite(e.venue.website);
                        tempSv.setFoursquare(e.venue.foursquare_link);
                        tempSv.setLatitude(e.venue.latitude);
                        tempSv.setLongitude(e.venue.longitude);
                        tempSv.setCategory(jtheme.icon);
                        tempSv.setIcon(jtheme.icon);
                        // language depending
                        if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("nld")){ //dutch
                            tempSv.setTip(e.venue.tip); 
                            tempSv.setTheme(jtheme.name); 
                        } else { //english
                             tempSv.setTip(e.venue.tip_en); 
                             tempSv.setTheme(jtheme.name_en); 
                        }
                        // put two (useless) photos items
                        for (int m = 0; m<2;m++) {
                            String large="pic1";
                            String medium="pic1";
                            tempSv.photos.add(new SimplePhotos(large,medium));                                    
                            k++;
                        }    
                    }
                }
            jsonResponse.remove(i); // 
            }
        }
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // XXX Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // XXX Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return language;
}
```

SimpleVenue:

```
public class SimpleVenue implements Serializable, Comparable<SimpleVenue>{
        /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int ID;
    public String name;
    public String category;
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public String tip;
    public String phone;
    public String website;
    public String foursquare;
    public float latitude;
    public float longtitude;
    public String theme;
    public String icon;
    public String exception;
    public List<SimplePhotos> photos;
```

SimplePhotos;

```
public class SimplePhotos implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String medium;
    public String large;


    public SimplePhotos(String vmedium,String vlarge){
        medium = vmedium;
        large = vlarge;
    }

    public void setMedium(String vmedium){
        medium = vmedium;
    }

    public void setLarge(String vlarge){
        large = vlarge;
    }

    public String getMedium(){
        return medium;
    }

    public String getLarge(){
        return large;
    }
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work. I'm doing all this in an AsyncTast do in Background, could it be that it has anything to do with that?
Or am i just making some stupid mistake i can't find. I used objectslists in objectslist before, but never had this problem. My error is on the line

> tempSv.photos.add(new SimplePhotos(large,medium));

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? You could also create SimplePhotos on the line before then test to see if it is null before trying to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the full declaration however it doesn't appear that you are initialising the `photos` list within the `SimpleVenue` class. You need to assign an instance of a class that implements the `List` interface to this field. For example:

```
public List<SimplePhotos> photos = new ArrayList<SimplePhotos>();
```

Comment: But in the SimpleVenue class i already have: public List<SimplePhotos> photos;  Isn't that enough?

Comment: @japser No, that's just declaring a field that can hold a reference to a list. Fields are initialised to null by default which is why you get the NPE when you try and call the add() method on it. You need to assign the field to reference an actual object before you can invoke the add() method.

Comment: Russel thank you, i did as you suggested and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem as if tempSv.photos is null (Has not been initialized yet (Probably want this in your constructor))

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the photos List of tempSv. You have to add something like tempSv .photos = new ArrayList();